# ajax in magento not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento

I am just beginner of Magento. I want to run an ajax in Magento from my .phtml file.I read a [blog](http://www.atwix.com/magento/ajax-requests-in-magento/) fot it but did not get any success.I just want to send a mail to my client when ever a form is submitted on Product Page.

This is my .phmtl file path and code.

```
 path - web/frontierFinal/app/design/frontend/default/frontier/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and code

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo 

    $this->getUrl('groupedajax/ajax/index') ?>",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: "size=434",
                            success: function(data) {
                            $j('#thankyou').html(data);
                            }
                        });
```

I just followed the steps of the above mentioned blog as

1) First I create a module named groupedajax `/web/frontierFinal/groupedajax`

and then a new directory controllers and .php file `/web/frontierFinal/groupedajax/controllers/AjaxController.php`

then code of AjaxController.php

```
<?php
class Creare_Groupedajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "sasd";
    }
}
?>
```

then a xml file named config as `/httpdocs/web/frontierFinal/groupedajax/etc/config.xml`

and code of this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Creare_Groupedajax>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Creare_Groupedajax>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <groupedajax>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Creare_Groupedajax</module>
          <frontName>groupedajax</frontName>
        </args>
      </groupedajax>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <groupedajax>
          <file>groupedajax.xml</file>
        </groupedajax>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

then a mapping xml file as `/httpdocs/web/frontierFinal/app/design/frontend/default/frontier/layout/groupedajax.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
  <groupedajax_ajax_index>
    <block type="groupedajax/groupedajax" name="root" output="toHtml" template="template/catalog/product/view.phtml" />
  </groupedajax_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

I know I dont have clear understanding of directories thats why this problem is coming up.But I need your help guys.

When I run ajax it shows 404 not found.

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your directories are completely wrong. So Magento does not use any of your code.

Please look into tutorials like these for more info:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/
or
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part4-series-helloworld

Your base dir is `web/frontierFinal/`. Then everything should reside in it, mostly in `app`. That's where all files are located in those tutorials.

Comment: teras can you help me to run ajax any how from my .phtml file Please

Comment: @user3110655 - did you try to look into the links I posted? You have to add module activation file into `app/etc/modules` and place code files `app/code/local`.

Comment: I read the complete blog of your sent links but that is for creating module and I need to run AJAX Please help me

Comment: can you post a similar example for running AJAX too.with directory structures

Comment: I did a mistake placing two identical links. Sorry for that, now I fixed it. Second link contains image link where structure is shown. I do not see why I have to do the same work and I'll hardly do it better.

Comment: I followed second tutorial but giving me 404 error. where to put IndexController.php

Answer (score 0):

In your .phtml file use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery("#form_post").submit(function() {
    var posdata = jQuery("#form_post").serializeArray();
    var url = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('test/index/save') ?>";
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      datatype: "text",
      data: posdata,
      success: function(data)
      {
        $$(".result").invoke("update",data.replace(/\"/g, ""));
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

And in controller add

```
public function saveAction()
{
  $result=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('telephone');;
  $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```