# 404 error in ajax with magento

Tags: ajax, magento

I followed complete steps of this [blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part4-series-helloworld) to create module but it is giving me 404 error.

I want to perform ajax operation from .phtml file which path is as follows

```
web/frontierFinal/app/design/frontend/default/frontier/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

I created IndexController.php under controllers directory.

```
/httpdocs/web/frontierFinal/app/code/local/Excellence/Test/controllers

<?php
class Excellence_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
?>
```

When I run ajax it shows 404 not found error.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('Excellence/test/index') ?>",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "size=434",
                        success: function(data) {
                        $j('#thankyou').html(data);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What happen when you go to website.com/excellence/test (same as website.com/excellence/test/index)?

Comment: Please add the contents of /app/code/local/Excellence/Test/etc/config.xml into your post above.  You should have a frontend/routers block that specifies the front name of your contoller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax in magento not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061663/ajax-in-magento-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

App/code/local/vendor/modulename/controllers/test.php
App/code/local/modulename/etc/config.xml

This Error is due to 
In your etc/Config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
      <excellence>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>[vendor]_[modulename]</module>
                    <frontName>excellence</frontName>
                </args>
        </excellence>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

url: "getUrl('excellence/test/index') ?>"